# Why isn't flatlist not able to map through and display the data?

Tags: api, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using Zomato API to get the list of restaurants, data is in the form of the array which has object restaurants in which there are different restaurant objects and then their name and other details.

It's my first time using a flat List and I am not able to display this data.

Goal: Use the search bar to display the list of restaurants in the city using flatlist.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { search: '', data: [] };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'user-key': '999999999999999999999999999'
            },
            params: JSON.stringify({
                entity_type: 'city',
                q: {this.state.search}
            }),
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => { return this.setState({ data: responseJson.restaurants }) })
            .catch((error) => { console.warn(error) }
            );
    }

    render() {
        let data = this.state.data;
        let name = data.map(p => p.restaurant.name)
        console.warn("Check Data", name)
        return (
            <View>
                <SearchBar
                    round
                    searchIcon={{ size: 24 }}
                    placeholder='Search'
                    onChangeText={search => { this.setState({ search }) }}
                    value={this.state.search}
                />
//Using this method to display the data if any

                {name.length != 0 ?
                    <FlatList
                        data={name}
                        keyExtractor={(x, i) => x + i}
                        renderItem={({ name }) => <Text>{name}-DATA</Text>}
                    />
                    : <View style={{height:"100%", width:"100%", alignItems:"center", 
                                      justifyContent:"center"}}>
                        <Text>No data found</Text>
                    </View>
                }

            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

Maybe the way I declared state is wrong, or maybe the way I'm storing the data in the state is wrong.
I got the names of the restaurant in the console.warn successfully.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your users-key I can't surely understand what is your api results.
Here

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { search: '', data: [] };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://phplaravel-325095-1114213.cloudwaysapps.com/api/shop/shop/', {
            method: 'GET',
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => { return this.setState({ data: responseJson }) })
            .catch((error) => { alert(error) }
            );
    }

    render() {
        let data = this.state.data;
        return (
            <View>
                <SearchBar
                    round
                    searchIcon={{ size: 24 }}
                    placeholder='Search'
                    onChangeText={search => { this.setState({ search }) }}
                    value={this.state.search}
                />

                {data.length != 0 ?
                    <FlatList
                        data={data}
                        keyExtractor={(x, i) => x + i}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.name}-DATA</Text>}
                    />
                    : <View style={{height:"100%", width:"100%", alignItems:"center", 
                                      justifyContent:"center"}}>
                        <Text>No data found</Text>
                    </View>
                }

            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

This is a working code with another api call just add your api call instead on mine.. This is working properly. I guess you are just messing with your data.

Comment: Hey, thanks this worked I still don't know what the actual issue was. I changed "<Text>{item.name}-DATA</Text>" to "{item.restaurant.name}" and also stopped mapping the name of restaurant in const name.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the `renderItem` from `FlatList` to

```
renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item}-DATA</Text>}
```

Also, replace the condition to use double equals like `name.length !== 0`

Comment: Hey Ian, it's still showing a flatlist with "-DATA" written over 20 times (20 times cuz of API limit to display 20 restaurants in the first call)

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't notice you already extracted the name property. Then, it should be fine if you only use `item` inside the text.

Comment: Hey, tried it just now got an error stating Objects are not valid as a React child ( found: Object with keys {resrtaurant}). If you meant to render  a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Are you sure you did it the way you had it? I mean, with out changing the data source to use the state directly. If you are using `name`, it won't be an array of objects anymore.

Comment: Otherwise, please post the response you are getting. As I can see from the docs, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the url link properly.

https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search/999999999999999999999999999

Just check it on web browser it is showing message : The requested url was not found

It means we are not getting any data from this URL.
That why we are not able to map any data.

Comment: Hey, you are getting this error cuz I didn't mention my actual user key.

Comment: So don't map it into third variable name just pass the state value directly in data of flatlist means  Instead of data={name} use data={this.state.data}

Comment: Hey, Changed it to data = {this.state.data}, still the result is same "-DATA" over 20 times.

Comment: data={this.state.data} and renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.name}-DATA</Text>} Try it out, it will definitely work

Comment: Hey no luck with this either, showing "-Data" 20 times in the flatlist with no restaurant names.